# UIView animation is not work properly in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, autolayout

I want to create animation like below, I done this in iOS 11.2.

[image: Working Animation]

I test this in iOS 8.4 and 9.2 - `broke`

[image: Broken Animation]

## Storyboard

I used autoLaout 
[image]

## RoundedShadowButton

I subclassed UIButton. Added RoundedCorner and DropShadow protocols to it. It contains a animateButton function that cares the animation.

```
class RoundedShadowButton: UIButton, RoundedCorner, DropShadow {
    var originalSize: CGRect?

    func animateButton(shouldLoad: Bool, withMessage message: String?) {
        let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
        spinner.color = .darkGray
        spinner.alpha = 0.0
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
        spinner.tag = 21

        if shouldLoad {
            self.addSubview(spinner)
            self.setTitle("", for: .normal)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                self.setRoundedCorners(radius: self.frame.height / 2)
                self.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.midX - (self.frame.height / 2), y: self.frame.origin.y, width: self.frame.height, height: self.frame.height)
            }, completion: { (finished) in
                if finished {
                    spinner.startAnimating()
                    spinner.center = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 + 1, y: self.frame.width / 2 + 1)
                    spinner.fadeTo(alphaValue: 1.0, withDuration: 0.2)
                }
            })
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        } else {
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            // remove spinner
            for subView in self.subviews {
                if subView.tag == 21 {
                    subView.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }

            // return back to original button
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                if let size = self.originalSize {
                    self.setRoundedCorners(radius: 8)
                    self.frame = size
                    self.setTitle(message, for: .normal)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

## RoundedCorner

```
protocol RoundedCorner {}

extension RoundedCorner where Self: UIView {
    func setRoundedCorners(radius: CGFloat) {
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
    }
}
```

## DropShadow

```
protocol DropShadow {}

extension DropShadow where Self: UIView {
    func setShadow(width: CGFloat = 0, height: CGFloat = 0, opacity: Float, radius: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        layer.shadowRadius = radius
    }
}
```

## HomeVC

In HomeVC's viewDidAppear, I set the corner radius, shadow and frame size. In buttons IBAction I called the animate function.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        actionBtn.originalSize = actionBtn.frame
        actionBtn.setRoundedCorners(radius: 8)
        actionBtn.setShadow(opacity: 0.3, radius: 10.0, color: .darkGray)
    }

@IBAction func actionBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.actionBtn.animateButton(shouldLoad: true, withMessage: nil)
    }
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Most likely your leading/trailing constraints prevents it from sizing. Although it has worked, it is not something you can rely on. When using constraints you need to resize your items with constraints also.

Comment: @Sh_Khan not worked

Comment: @LGP I changed the priority to 999, not helped. Any idea from your side

Comment: See my solution below.

Comment: just check it without contraints and handle manually (means remove all contraints ). it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When animating with constraints you need to work with the constraints also. Although it may worked sometimes, it is not something you can rely on. You can solve it like this.

- Remove the `leading` and `trailing` constraints.
- Add a width constraint with `same width` as `superview` minus `40`. Connect this to a class variable of type `NSLayoutConstraint` named `widthConstraint`. Set priority `750`.
- Add another width constraint that has `width` set to same as height so it becomes a circle. Set priority to `500`.
- Add a constraint to `center` within `superview`.

Now, in your code replace the frame modification part.

```
            self.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.midX - (self.frame.height / 2), y: self.frame.origin.y, width: self.frame.height, height: self.frame.height)
```

With this. By changing priority you choose which constraint should be in effect. Since the wide constraint is at 750, it will win over the narrow constraint. When changing priority to 250, the narrow constraint will win.

```
            self.widthConstraint.priority = 250
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Where I create the width constraint ? I created it in storyboard but, how to change its constant value? Because the animation function in RoundedShadowButton class

Comment: Yes, create it like any other constraint in Storyboard. If you double click on the constraint you will get a property page for it, there you can connect it to your variable.

Comment: But the variable in HomeVC, how to access it in RoundedShadowButton class

Comment: Pass it as a parameter to `animateButton` or (perhaps better) set it as a weak property on `RoundedShadowButton` object.

Comment: Expands? Not sure how that can happen. Did you remove the leading/trailing constraints for the button?

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!, I created this in RoundedShadowButton

Comment: Perhaps you changed scope for the animation? My assignment relies on that `self.frame.height` is the button.

Comment: Expands because I set equal width to superView and change the constant to -40, In animation I give the frame height so it expand

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You are right. Let me update the solution.

Comment: OK, so I improved it to actually work as intended, I hope. Also I moved the actual sizes to both be set from the storyboard. What you do now is just change `priority` on one constraint, making it switch to the other size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working at my end simply disable this :

```
   self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
```